# Blur images no matter what in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button with an image and no matter what I do the image looks blurry after rendered/compiled.

FYI - The image looks good when not in WPF controls

The image on the `left` is before compiled, the image on the `right` is blurry after compiled.

[image]

I tried applying UseLayoutRounding, applying SnapsToDevicePixels,
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode and removing the antialiasing directly in the button and directly to the image but nothing.

Any idea how can I improve the quality of the images in WPF?

**XAML:**

Styles applied directly to the button:

```
  <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="recentButton" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
            Margin="10,137,302,10"
            Width="auto"
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <Image Source="/Tool;component/Design/Images/more-icon-active.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Styles applied directly to the image:

```
  <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="recentButton"
            Margin="10,137,302,10"
            Width="auto"
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <Image Source="/Tool;component/Design/Images/more-icon-active.png" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Height` attribute? Assuming that the image is 23 pixels in height, there may be some default padding causing it to be slightly smaller.

Comment: Also, try to use `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the parent window instead of on the button.

Comment: @scharette Adding `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the parent container did the trick. `<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True"><Button></Button></Grid>`. I actually removed the rest of the styling, do you think I should keep some of that? `UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" `. You may want to reply as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Depending on the kind of image, `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` may add some sharpness.

Comment: @Clemens - Would you apply that to the parent container as well or directly to the image?

Comment: Only to the Image element.

Comment: I'd also highly recommend setting `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` on your top level elements to greatly improve text rendering on desktop computers.  Otherwise you can end up with slightly blurry text.

Comment: I like how the text looks by applying `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"`, thanks.

Comment: @Clemens Added your recommendation to the answer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Added your recommendation to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using [`UseLayoutRounding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.110).aspx) on the control directly.

But, be aware of this note in the linked documentation,

> You should set UseLayoutRounding to true on the root element. The layout system adds child coordinates to the parent coordinates; therefore, if the parent coordinates are not on a pixel boundary, the child coordinates are also not on a pixel boundary. If UseLayoutRounding cannot be set at the root, set SnapsToDevicePixels on the child to obtain the effect that you want.

Therefore, **use it on the parent container instead**. In your case, that would be on the on the `<grid>` element.

---

**Other recommandations**

1. Recommended by @Clemens in the comment section,

*Depending on the kind of image, `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` may add some sharpness.*

Note that you will have to apply that on the image directly.

2. Recommended by @BradleyUffner in the comment section,

*Setting `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` on your top level elements to greatly improve text rendering on desktop computers.*